# Change Django's settings from an external source

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I would like to write a script in Python to edit my Django application settings.py file. Other than reading the file as a text file, is there any other way I can edit the values of the variables in the settings file and save it?

Answer (score 4):

> other than reading the file as a text file is there any other way I can edit the values of the variables in the settings file and save it?

There is no need to parse & rewrite settings.py as such. Just add a statement like this:

```
import json
overrides = json.loads(open('settings.json').read())
globals().update(overrides)
```

`settings.json` then contains your settings like this:

```
{
  "MY_SETTING" : "FOO"
}
```

I'm using a .json file here as an example. As long as `overrides` is a dictionary, you can use any source that returns a dictionary (e.g. yml, your own format, or even a python's class `__dict__`).

As a result, `settings` as imported from `django.conf` will contain the new setting as if it was specified directly in `settings.py`:

```
$ python manage.py shell
In [1]: print settings.MY_SETTING
FOO
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @miraculixx . I was not very clear in my question. I have 4 django apps and the settings file of all four apps are quite similar but the database name, passwords, hosts etc are different. I don't want to directly edit in each settings.py file. Instead i created a json file with all the settings variables and When I need to change the settings.py file of an app I want to run the python script and read the values in the json file and if there is any changes in the json file valuesthen I want to change the value in settings file

Comment: the above solution will do all that, however, you don't need to change the settings.py though. it is automatically executed when django loads. note that generally the way to go for this kind of thing is to store database name, password, host in environment variables and use `os.environ.get('YOUR_VARIABLE')`.

Comment: I wish I'd known this before coding my own solution! Question: Will this watch the external file, i.e. restart the server if the external file changes?

Comment: you will have to try, but AFAIK Django's development server (runserver) only monitors python files

Answer (score 1):

You want something like [django-appconf](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-appconf).

Answer (score 1):

Inside your primary settings.py you can do something like the following:

```
from portal.base.settings import add_portal_settings
globals().update(add_portal_settings(locals()))
```

The content of portal.base.settings is something like:

```
def add_portal_settings(settings):
  settings['PORTAL_URL'] = "portal_account_login"
  return settings
```

This will then work:

```
from django.conf import settings
print(settings.PORTAL_URL)
```